# inet_pton not declared in scope

Tags: qt, mingw32

I'm currently working on client application and all is going well until I try and build on my Windows 7 machine, the project will compile and run perfectly on Vista and Linux Mint15.

I get an error inet_pton not declared in scope

On Windows 7 and Linux I use MinGW on Vista the MSVC compiler all using QT 5.2.0
I get the impression its a MinGW on Windows issue? Obviously Linux is using the other includes

The includes:

```
#if defined(WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <wspiapi.h>
#include <string>  // DJM: Cannot have <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <w32api.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif



    bool Socket::connect ( const std::string &host, const int port )
{
  if ( ! is_valid() ) return false;
  m_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  m_addr.sin_port = htons ( port );
  int status = inet_pton ( AF_INET, host.c_str(), &m_addr.sin_addr );
#ifndef WIN32
  if ( errno == EAFNOSUPPORT ) return false;
#endif
  status = ::connect ( m_sock, ( sockaddr * ) &m_addr, sizeof ( m_addr ) );
  if ( status == 0 )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

The includes are the result of searching for an answer and nothing seems to work :/

I guess the quick solution is to install  QT MSVC2010, but it would be cool if there was a code option :)

Comment: Could you please clarify how this question relates to Qt?

Comment: I'm using QT to create the client application, my primary computer uses QT 5.2.1 with MinGW.
After doing some more research it seems to be a MinGW issue, so the easy option is to use MSVC instead.... But seeing as its a know problem it would be interesting to see if there's a way to compile with MinGW

Comment: But I do not see any Qt code here. You are only using POSIX and the standard library here.

Comment: Its a general MinGW problem, a long running on by all accounts, so I just used MSVC and it compiles fine and with QT on Linux and Mac also.